# Materials science for game programming

Tags: simulation, game-physics

Does anybody know of a good resource for programming the behaviors of various materials interacting?

Game programming physics resources usually cover collision detection, momentum, intertia, etc., but they seem to deal with a sort of idealized "material".  I'm interested in simulating behavior of, say a projectile striking metal, which would deform more plastically, vs. one striking wood, which would tend to splinter, or glass, which would shatter.

Is there a book or online resource that deals with this from a game/simulation perspective?

Comment: You might want to wiki this.  There isn't a right answer.  But its a very interesting idea. +1

Comment: I think there is a right answer for a material scientist, and it's a serious commercial analysis package.

Comment: I think that a game can be satisfied with a slightly lower standard.  I'd call it "realistic looking", from a player's perspective, versus precise simulation that a scientist would require.

Comment: @Buggieboy - exactly my point.  It's not to disparage games.  Realism isn't the same as simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this [gamedev.net article on material deformation](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1459.asp) has a lot of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in things like simulating projectiles striking metal, plastic deformation, fracturing glass, etc. I don't think games will offer you much that's based on rigorous physics.

Those kinds of calculations are usually done using finite element analysis packages like ANSYS, NASTRAN,[ABAQUS](http://www.simulia.com/products/abaqus_fea.html) etc.  If you're a material scientist, and you want more than an empirical answer, I would say that gaming engines wouldn't have the fidelity that you're looking for.

I loaded the material deformation article that chaos posted.  I'm firmly in the FEA camp.

[LS Dyna](http://www.lstc.com/) is another contender that you should check out.  It's used for highly non-linear impact problems as well.